# Wrap UITextView inside UIView

Tags: swift, uiview, uitextview, uitableview

I'm creating a chat based app and on the conversation thread, I am using a `UIView` with a layout constraint of trailing to superview of 46px to ensure the chat bubble will be at least 46px from the right of the table view cell. Within the `UIView` I have a child `UITextView` which is constrained to the parent view on the top, bottom, and left. Since the text view's width can vary, I did not put a constraint on the right.

How can I get the `UITextView` to wrap it's text within the bounds of the `UIView`? If I don't have the clip subviews enabled on the `UIView`, the longer messages overflow the view and go past the end of the table view cell. If I have the clip subviews enabled, the longer messages are just clipped and don't get wrapped.

If I use a constraint on the trailing end of the `UITextView`, the width of the text view doesn't change. This makes the chat bubble much longer than the message.

Could anyone help point me in the right direction?

Comment: To clarify, you're putting chat bubbles _inside_ of a UITableViewCell?

Comment: Yes that's correct. I have a UITableView cell with one of the views inside is the UIView with the UITextView as it's child.

Comment: For the `UITextView` in the attributes inspector, do you have scrolling enabled?

Comment: No the scrolling enabled is not checked

Comment: Enable scrolling and see what happens.

Comment: When I enable scrolling, the table view cell height is too small to see what is inside the `UITextView`.

Comment: You are already heavily constrained if you're putting chat bubbles in table view cells. The only way to maximize a textview without scrolling is to make the text as small of a font as possible and/or maximize the textview inside of the constraints. If you don't want scrolling or editing functionality, I would suggest using a UILabel instead of a UITextView or UITextField if you're looking only to display un-editable text (which in a table view cell should be the case) and then set the UILabel's lines attribute to the number of lines you'd like displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Thank for you the assistance. I ended up using UILabel. I found out I shouldn't be using `sizeToFit()`, but instead set `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` for the `UILabel`. This post really helped me [UILabel sizeToFit and constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15927086/uilabel-sizetofit-and-constraints/15927392).